# Can this past participle also be an adjective?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, past-participles

A recent word game used

> "dwelt",

which surprised me because they usually don't include conjugations of verbs, unless they are also adjectives, like e.g. "burnt". Can

> "dwelt"

be an adjective? The only example I could come up with was something like "the house looked ______ in", but then that probable needs a hyphen, and even then, is it really an adjective?

Is there perhaps a rule that all past participles can be adjectives, even if their use would make no logical sense?

Comment: @livresque Wordle doesn't offer any way to play yesterday's word, after 24 hours it's gone, so there's no need to hide the word behind spoiler alerts. Besides, it's right there in the title :-)

Comment: It's still before midnight in parts of the world.  As soon as I saw your title I knew what you were referencing.

Comment: @livresque Oh, I thought the word changed at the same moment all arund the word. Shall I remove the question and post it again tomorrow?

Comment: That would be polite.  Also encourage you to check a dictionary.

Comment: @livresque I can't delete it myself. Can you delete it for me, or flag it for deletion?

Comment: It says [delete] right near [edit] under the question; you can do that more quickly than flagging on my end, thanks.

Comment: The *OED* lists this adjective.  But marks it as "obsolete".  Its example is from 1610.

Comment: @abc123 Ideally, you should register your account, which will enable the delete button for you. I could also delete it for you, but if I do, you'd have to flag for mod attention to get it undeleted.

Comment: I feel your pain. Wasn’t *leapt* an answer a while back? The (Wordle) problem is that the *New York Times* changed up / continues to change up the original bank of words (which now seems to include participles such as these as well as an occasional plural).

Comment: How can it possibly be both a past participle (i.e. a verb) and an adjective at the same time? When past participles are used with nouns, e.g. "[The guns stolen in the break-in] were recovered", they are not adjectives but **modifiers**.

Comment: ... though conversion is common.

Comment: There's a difference, compare: "The **stolen** guns were recovered (past-participial adjective as attributive modifier) / "The guns **stolen in the break-in** were recovered" (past participial form of verb as head of clause).

Comment: The rule is that all past participles are **potential** adjectives, if you need for them to be. As for whether that one there is an adjective or a verb form, that's the sort of question that can't be answered without changing the environment. Sort of Schrōdinger's part of speech.

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase John Lawler's comment, any past participle can potentially serve as an adjective if the occasion arises. Whether it pleases readers' stylistic senses is another matter. Here are a few examples of *dwelt* serving as an adjective in pre-position:

> Every compressed house thus became a place with its own memory, part of the larger collective memory of the **dwelt place**. (*[Place as Material Culture: Objects, Geographies, and the Construction of Time](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Place_as_Material_Culture/sF0xBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the%20dwelt%20place%22&pg=PA177&printsec=frontcover)*, 2013.)

> In this world, the dead mark the time in the life of communities - dead bodies lay the foundations of **dwelt space**, and they inhabit it after the occupation ended, as happens at many other tells. (*[Far from Equilibrium: An Archaeology of Energy, Life, and Humanity](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Far_from_Equilibrium_An_archaeology_of_e/NOcXEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22dwelt%20space%22&pg=PT98&printsec=frontcover)*, 2021.)

> But they've auxiliars there from many a town, / Spear-wielding men, that every effort mine / Put quite abroad, nor suffer me to crown / My wish, and overthrow fair Ilium's **well-dwelt town**. (*The Iliad of Homer, Literally Rendered in Spenserian Stanza*, 1864; note the use of the adverb *well* to modify *dwelt*.)

Conventionally, such an adjective usage is rare. You'll find many guides (like this from the [University of Victoria Continuing Studies](https://continuingstudies.uvic.ca/elc/studyzone/490/grammar/participial-adjectives)) focus on narrower sets of participial adjectives, like those showing emotion. Nonetheless, occasionally other participles are used as adjectives.